# Attribute ??? must have present attributes name or ref, but not both"

Tags: xml, wsdl

I'm trying to consume a Webservice created with PHP using SOAP standards with Visual Studio 2010 client.

When I try to generate the proxy, an error raises about the format of the WSDL file. The error message is this (translated so inacurate):

> Error in a ComplexType schema element named "Inscritos",
>   Attribute ??? must have present attributes name or ref, but not both

Reviewing the WSDL I found this element:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="Inscritos">
   <xsd:complexContent>
     <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
       <xsd:attribute res="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:Inscritos2[]"/>
     </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:complexContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

The WS is hosted by a external provider so we have no chance to redefine it. Does anybody Know a way or Workaround to avoid this issue??

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that the `xsd:attribute` tag should have attribute `ref` and not `res`. Try changing

```
<xsd:attribute res="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:Inscritos2[]"/>
```

to

```
<xsd:attribute ref="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:Inscritos2[]"/>
                 ^
```

Comment: Thanks Erik, but when I made this change another error raises in this WSDL line:  Error in document XML (126,20) Prefix of namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad schema, and I've no idea what it was supposed to mean, so I can't suggest a correction.

You ask what you can do if your project is relying on a service from an external supplier that is not fit for purpose. That's a project management question, not a technical question.

Comment: I think there is a technical way to achieve this workaround but I am not founding it, so this is the motivation that bring me here to ask for help. Perhaps an Approach could be to download the WSDL, and modify to make it compatible with VS2010 client proxy generator. Then use wsdl.exe command line to generate the client proxy. The problem is that I don't know what I have to modify in this element to make it work correctly